# Virtual packages with reprepro?

Tags: ubuntu, zentyal-linux, reprepro

I have been working on making Zentyal packages possible on the armhf architecture, and finally succeeded in a working build of 4.0 packages.

However the installation is quirky as these packages have a LOT of dependencies, and apt-get does not continue with the install interface of the separate packages. So I thought, let's make a repo out of them, and make it available to all!

The thing is - Zentyal uses virtual packages to install. And I simply couldn't find any information on how to add virtual packages to a repo using reprepro.

Is there anything simpler than manually adding the entries to the Release file and re-creating the repo with reprepro?

Comment: are they "meta" packages? packages that install a list of packages?

Comment: Yes. Meta packages are the virtual packages (depends on definition, but aptitude uses the term virtual and meta for the same term).

Comment: Cool, I have a small arm box, would be interested in this as well, hopefully you can find out how to do this.

Comment: Can you tell me the specs? Most important would be the arch - I only built the armhf packages, and some of the packages won't build (e.g. sope, roundcube). The Build guide is quite outdated and does not cover the additional packages...

Comment: has a A20, arm cortex a7, 1gig of ram, if that is similar I might be able to try some tests and try building.

Comment: Okay, the A20 images use the same armhf arch, so it's a good start. I'll upload the packages as soon as I'm done testing everything out!